# spring context:property-placeholder only loads file with the very specific name jdbc.properties

Tags: spring, applicationcontext

I'm using spring 3.0 and trying to load a properties file:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myFile.properties" />
...
<property name="userName" value="${myVariable}" />
```

...

Using a `xpto.properties`, when I try to use any parameter from this file if shows me the error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Invalid bean definition with name 'myBean' defined in class path
>   resource [myApplicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder
>   'myVariable'...

The strange thing is if I use file with the very specific name `jdbc.properties` it works!
I searched  for any reference or filter of `jdbc.properties` in my project and found nothing.

ps. one important thing: properties file is in the classpath, the error is not to load the file, it is when I trying to use any variable from this file (except if file name is jdbc)

Can someone give me a light?

Comment: did you add  <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
<property name="location"><value>classpath:your properties file name</value></property>
 </bean>

Comment: I just tried to use it and I got the same error. What I'm actually using is <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:myProperties.properties" />

Comment: But you need to first register the `propety-placeholder` with spring container.http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/. Go through this website.It will be helpful to you to understand how to use `propety` files in spring.

Comment: Are the `property-placeholder` and the `${myVariable}` in the same XML file or in different ones?

Comment: Is `myVariable` defined in `xpto.properties`? Or is it just defined in `jdbc.properties`?

Comment: It worked now! There project depend on another parent project and the placeholder was already defined in this parent (as jdbc.properties). So I only have to change parent. I didn't find before because this parent project was closed in eclipse when I tried to search. Thanks everybody for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It worked now! There project depend on another parent project and the placeholder was already defined in this parent (as jdbc.properties). So I only have to change parent. I didn't find before because this parent project was closed in eclipse when I tried to search. Thanks everybody for the help